# PHP function using unlink() and rmdir() not working

Tags: php

I am trying to delete a directory which is being created when I create an article.

What I am trying to do is delete the folder together with the file after I delete the article from the db,but it seams its not working.

I am using this function

```
function deleteFiles(string $path) {
    $files = glob($path . '/*');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        is_dir($file) ? $this -> deleteFiles($file) : unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($path);
}
```

And I called it like this for testing.

```
 deleteFiles('/home/emp/sub.domainx.com/en/test');
```

No error is showing up in the console regarding this.

Does anyone have any ideea why this is not working?Thank you.

Comment: do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Don't use spaces on this line `$this -> deleteFiles($file)` this is a syntax error. Turn on `error_reporting(true)` and try this `$this->deleteFiles($file)`

Comment: most probably the issue is with Directory Permission. 
Try changing en/test folder's permission 0777

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs i am getting this Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to deleteFiles() must be an instance of string, string given,

Comment: @zan Typefunctions are only available on `PHP7+`. What version of PHP do you use?

Comment: @Variable i think its 5.6

Comment: @zan Yes, but type for `string` and so on, is only available in 7. [Read here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Comment: @Variable i removed the string from the function and let only $path and i think its working :D.  function deleteFiles($path)

Comment: Not only `$this -> ` is syntax error, it doesn't look like `deleteFiles()` is member of a class at all judging from your first call, why are you putting `$this->` in there?

Comment: Also, `glob()` may return `.` as one of the results which would create an infinite loop, and `..` which will cause this function to delete files outside the specified path aswell.

Comment: @Havenard what do you suggest ? i am no expert , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you enabled the `error_reporting(E_ALL)` on development mode. Make sure you have the rights to edit folders/files. Mostly you have to chmod the files/folders to `777`. Refered to the comments, type declarations are available on PHP5. However declarations for:

> string,
>   float,
>   bool,
>   int,
>   iterable  (>= 7.1),
>   object (>= 7.2)

Are only available from PHP7+ according to the [PHP.net docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) and will give you a fatal error for example:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to test() must be an instance of boolean, boolean given, called in - on line 1 and defined in -:1

Removing `string` should to the trick if you are using PHP5.

```
function deleteFiles($path) {
    $files = glob($path . '/*');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        is_dir($file) ? $this->deleteFiles($file) : unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($path);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help , any ideea how I should do it without using $this-> ?

Comment: @zan Is your function inside a class? If not, remove `$this->`.

Comment: is it good if no class ? i mean as a code , and how can i create a function class for it ? thank you

Comment: @zan Make sure you have seen this page: https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php :-)